# Some Flask routes works on HTTP but not on HTTPS

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, deployment, https, server

I have a flask app that runs fine on my local machine with all routes working fine. However, when I run the same flask app using gunicorn over an EC2 ubuntu server, only "/" route works and others doesn't.

app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("someForm.html")

@app.route('/someForm', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def interestForm():
    args = request.args
    args = args.to_dict()
    emailID = args.get('email')

    <Some python Logic here>
    return render_template("someForm.html", somevariable = Value1, somevariable = value2)

@app.route('/submit', methods=['GET'])
def submit():
    args = request.args
    args = args.to_dict()
    email = args.get('email')

    <Some python backend logic that updates form value of the corresponding email in the database>

    if updateTable(email, updateDic)==1:
        return redirect("someURL")
    else:
        return render_template("someForm.html", error_message = "Issue with updating")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.jinja_env.auto_reload = True
    app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000, threaded=True)
```

**More Info on the deployment**
I run the flask app using the command below

`nohup gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app &`

Also configured the NGINX server to point to localhost:8000

> Inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
upstream flaskhelloworld {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

# Some code above
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://flaskhelloworld;
}
# some code below
```

I have configured DNS using Cloudflare and issued an SSL certificate using certbot. All works fine as I can access `https://www.domain_name.com` but I can't access `https://www.domain_name.com/someForm` neither I can access `https://www.domain_name.com/someForm?=email@gmail.com` through browser (tested on Chrome and edge)

**TEST cases and other checks**

1. I tried to `curl https://www.domain_name.com` and it returns the HTML correctly. But when I `curl https://www.domain_name.com/someForm` I get the result below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

#### Confusing case

**Interestingly, when I use HTTP instead of HTTPS while using Thunderclient or Curl command, it returns the proper results with a 200 status code.**

`curl http://domain_name.com/someForm?email=kaushal@gmail.com`
[![results][2]][2]

Only thing that works with HTTPS is the home route (i.e. "/")
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPZW4.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LF9m.png

Comment: are you using certbot to manage https? If your code works well without https on the server, certbot will allow you to quickly enable https

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the question, I do use CertBot. The issue is not with HTTPS as the home route is accessible but no other routes are accessable.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said, I think all of your requests are going to /
Here is a working configuration for https using certbot that will pass things to the correct spaces

```
server {
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params; # this is what I think you are missing
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/myProject.sock; # this is from a gunicorn configuration but it could just be a proxy pass
    }




    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

You should only write this part yourself:

```
location / {
        include proxy_params; # this is what I think you are missing
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/myProject.sock; # this is from a gunicorn configuration but it could just be a proxy pass
    }
```

and allow certbot to do the rest

Comment: I don't have a file similar to `myProject.sock`.

Though I tried adding the line `include proxy_params` and restarted the nginx server `sudo systemctl restart nginx` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated my post with the line I have added

Comment: do one thing, try adding 
upstream flaskhelloworld {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000/; # a slash at the end
}
and also try using curl internally to see if your server is responding correctly

Comment: After adding the slash I am getting this error
`nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "127.0.0.1:8000/" in /etc/nginx/s>`

||||| I did `curl localhost:8000` and `curl localhost:8000/someForm?email=someemail` inside the ec2 server and both works as expected

Comment: if curl works as expected, its likely an issue with your UFW configuration.
you could use something like "sudo UFW allow 80" which will allow nginx